# Making all lines uniform color in graph after using melt() function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used `melt` so that I could easily display several lines on the same graph using ggplot2. However, this only really works when I have the color set to variable. When I try to change it to black or any other color I get this unfortunate pattern. I am sure this is a quick fix but I can't figure it out

```
df.melted <- melt(john, id = "sample_size")
GRAPH<-ggplot(data = df.melted, aes(x = sample_size, y = value, color = variable))+
  geom_line()+theme_classic()+coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,100))+theme(legend.position="none")+
```

The resulting graph is here...
[image]

And when I try to change set the color = "black" in either aes() or geom_line() I get these red lines:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at [how to make reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). In your case, you can set color with e.g. `scale_colour_discrete`.

Comment: try replacing colour with group in the aes()

Comment: `color="black"` inside `aes` is treated like a new factor column of data that takes on only one value, "black", and is mapped to a single default color (because there's only one factor level) by ggplot, which happens to be red. You could replace "black" with anything and the result would be the same. Try these, for example, `ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, colour="black")) + geom_line()` or `ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, colour="mimsy")) + geom_line()`. But this will give you black: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_line(color="black")` (black is the default, so you don't really need to set it).

Comment: Also, in your case, as @RichardTelford said, you need `group=variable` inside `aes` in order to get separate lines for each value of variable.

Comment: Thanks...switching group and color worked perfectly! Thanks a bunch!